# How to populate drowndown box using spring+hibernate,jsp

Tags: javascript, ajax, spring, hibernate, jsp

I am new in this world...so please help..I want idea from u people...I have 4 dropdown list  ..and I wanted to populate select box on selecting another selectbox2 .... using database values....so how should I proceed ..i need your help...and i have already created the database for that...and I am good with database....so please help me..forward me some link also..I have short span of time..within that i have to complete..please help.

Comment: clearify more your question with some code and efforts done by you.

Comment: okay...actuly I lookin for the basic concept.....so that i can start it on a proper way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Spring 3.0 you can populate values in the dropdown as follows:

```
  @ModelAttribute("webFrameworkList")
public List<String> populateWebFrameworkList() {

    //Data referencing for web framework checkboxes
    List<String> webFrameworkList = new ArrayList<String>();
    webFrameworkList.add("Spring MVC");
    webFrameworkList.add("Struts 1");
    webFrameworkList.add("Struts 2");
    webFrameworkList.add("JSF");
    webFrameworkList.add("Apache Wicket");

    return webFrameworkList;
}
```

In JSP

```
<form:select path="favFramework">
   <form:options items="webFrameworkList"/>
</form:select>
```

Now you can modify the logic as per your requirement that you want.

Comment: thanks for your comment...here I have to use four different spring controller..to handle those dropdown box????....sorry i am new in the spring

Comment: can u please forward me some link related to this concept..so that i can refer..

Comment: First i request you to read spring docs and then you can follow http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-dropdown-box-example/